# Will errors in using articles harm the chance of getting admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I have applied to a university in the US that has a ranking of 130-150. I have just found that in my Personal Statement /  Statement of Purpose, I have made two mistakes using the **definite article** in my Statement of Purpose. Will these **two mistakes** in **the Articles** harm my chance of getting admission?

The SOP is 1200 words in length.

I have applied to the Physiology PhD program.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

No one is going to reject an application that *otherwise* warrants admission because of two typos, even more so if it’s from a non-native speaker as in your case.