# Will two typographical errors can harm the chances of getting accepted into a PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have submitted a Ph.D. application to a university with a ranking from 100 to 120 in the US. As I am preparing for my next application, I have found out two typos in my CV (3 pages long), one extra comma, and one uppercase "P" in the middle of a word. I have also found that in my SOP (2 pages long), I have mistakenly placed the preposition "in", where the correct preposition should be "with". Other than these, there are no mistakes in my application, at least from my point of view (I am a non-native speaker).

Will these mistakes harm my chances of getting accepted into the applied Ph.D. program?

My experience in brief:

I have 12 publications in journals ranging from 1.0 to 5.0 impact factors, 20 months of part-time research experience, 6 months of job experience, and am affiliated with 2 voluntary organizations for about 03 years (relevant to the program).

I have contacted the graduate manager and they informed me that no change can be made at this point.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between this question and this older question you asked two weeks ago? [Will errors in using articles harm the chance of getting admission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175960/will-errors-in-using-articles-harm-the-chance-of-getting-admission)

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143031/is-one-spelling-mistake-in-the-academic-cv-a-big-deal Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Admissions committees try to find the best candidates for the program. I do not expect any admissions committee to select an applicant with 0 typos and 0 research/publication experience over an applicant with 3 typos and 12 publications and more than a year of research experience. Your research experience seems better than what most applicants to a PhD program have, and you should not overthink the effect of those 3 typos. Just fix them for your next applications.

You may want to consider shortening your application documents though. Two-page CVs and one-page statements of purpose seem to be more common. Too long documents risk the chance of not being read in detail or even at all.

Comment: Unlike their industry counterparts, academic CVs don't have a space restriction. Mine is more than 10 pages and I got the last two jobs I applied for.